# App Engine doesn't generate composite indexes

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm following the Udacity's Developing Scalable Apps with Java tutorial and I'm trying to create a query by multiple properties, but it doesn't work.

Here is the Api method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "filterPlayground",path = "filterPlayground",httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public List<Conference> filterPlayground()
{
    Query<Conference>query = ofy().load().type(Conference.class).order("name");
    query.filter("city = ","London");
    query.filter("topics =", "Medical Innovations");
    query.filter("month = ", 6);

    return query.list();
}
```

and here are the fields in the Conference model:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_CITY = "Default City";

@Index private List<String> topics;
@Index(IfNotDefault.class) private String city = DEFAULT_CITY;
@Index private int month;
```

It just shows all the conferences. I don't understand why this doesn't work. By the way, when I deploy to localhost the datastore-indexes-auto.xml is always empty.

And here a link to the test:
https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://deft-envoy-650.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/conference/v1/conference.filterPlayground?_h=3&

I hope someone could help me with this.
Regards,

Comment: did you insert the entities before adding the index ?

Comment: Hi @koma, thanks for your answer. What do you mean by insert the entities before adding the index? I already have some records in the database. I have to delete them and start again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also working on the same course and struggled at this point as well. The datastore-indexes-auto.xml is just not being created, no matter what I do!

My workaround is as follows:

1) Create a file datastore-indexes.xml file in the folder: /conference/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datastore-indexes
autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="Conference" ancestor="false">
        <property name="city" direction="asc" />
        <property name="topics" direction="asc" />
        <property name="month" direction="asc" />
        <property name="name" direction="asc" />
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

(however, the autoGenerate="true" seems to have no effect)

2) deploy to appsot

This way the query that you posted above works for me. And I agree - the GAE version for which the course was made seems to be somewhat different as there are several issues I struggled with (i.e. I don´t seem to have a local datastore but every localhost execution is accessing my appspot datastore..).

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. What you are using is a simple (field) index. [Custom (or composite) index](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Index_configuration) is something else, not needed in your case as you only have equality filters. Your `datastore-indexes-auto.xml` is empty because in your case composite index is not needed.
2. Simple indexes are build automatically on each entity save/update, AFTER you declare them. So if you already had some entities in the DB and you declare a new index, the existing entities will not be updated.
3. For custom indexes auto-generate strategy is the opposite: after you declare a custom index, DB will go through all your existing entities and update the custom index. This can take some time, you can check in GAE Admin console when the index is ready.

Comment: thanks for your answer. That's the problem. But, Udacity's Course says it's a composite index, and the instructor is a Google Developer. I think they used a older GAE version.